# To get the nearest matching value in DB2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, case

I have a table with the following values

```
   ACCNO                  TEXT
   -------------     ----------------
   8611004050001     internal payment
   861100405000X     external payment
   8611XXXXXXXXX     other payments
```

suppose if the accono is 8611004050002 then i have to pic external payment.
if the accno is 8611211216223 then i have to get other payments.

I need to get the nearest matching value is single sql I have tried with case statement its not working. what is the efficient method to achieve this.

Pleas help me

Comment: ...The design of your table implies a multi-part key, which would be against recommended best practice.  At minimum, it also requires you know that the key's structure is important, which would be a related problem.  Depending on your future needs, changing the design may be warranted.

Comment: This is the requirement, I cant change the design..

This table is like a control table, based on this row(accno) they want to pick some values..I didnt give full table structure here

Comment: I can achieve this in program(using loop & multiple sql statement), but if i able to do it in single query, it will increase the performance..

Comment: _Usually_ doing things in one statement is more efficient.  Unfortunately, just about everything is likely to generate a table scan for this, because of the structure of the data - what you're trying to query isn't conductive to indexing.  This would be easier and faster if you had a properly designed table(s).  Oh, I'm assuming passing an account like `8724114159901` should result in none of your example rows from being chosen.  Also, how static are the groups?  Is it always the first 4 characters, all but the last, and everything?  Or does it change each time?

Comment: Are there non numeric character values in your account number string?

Comment: @proksh : 'XX' is wildcards and its non numeric char.

Comment: @clockwork : The first 2 num should match.. in your example 8724114159901 should give NRF.. atleast a row like 86XXXXXXXXX should present in the table...as per design first 2 digit of accno is number rest may be a wild card(like XXXX) or number...For an exp if accno has 86999999999 should pick text corresponding to accno 86XXXXXXXXX..if first 2 digits should match.

Comment: @DhanyaKUMAR.S - what are the other wild cards, and do you care about them?  Like something stating a specific character must be a digit or some letter?  Or what about non-contiguous wildcards (say, the third and last characters are wildcards), what happens then?  Also, what platform/version of DB2, please?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse :  As per requirement ACCNO field is char (12), the first 2 digit is number (in table in the form of char) rest might be num or wildcard..wildcards are like X or %.. these char i need to get conform... but it will be a X or %.. mostly It wont change..

Db2 version is 10(Version 10 Release 1).

Comment: ...Why are there **two different wildcards**!? :headdesk:  That should be fixed.  If your column was `VARCHAR(12)` and used the correct `LIKE`-related wildcards(single `%` for all trailing wildcards, `_` for non-contiguous ones - do you have any of these?) your query would be vastly simplified.  Still stuck doing a table scan, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, one method uses a giant `case` statement.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when accno = <accno> then 99
               when left(accno, 15) = left(<accno>, 15) then 15
               when left(accno, 14) = left(<accno>, 14) then 14
               when left(accno, 13) = left(<accno>, 13) then 13
               when left(accno, 12) = left(<accno>, 12) then 12
               when left(accno, 11) = left(<accno>, 11) then 11
               when left(accno, 10) = left(<accno>, 10) then 10
               when left(accno, 9) = left(<accno>, 9) then 9
               when left(accno, 8) = left(<accno>, 8) then 8
               when left(accno, 7) = left(<accno>, 7) then 7
               when left(accno, 6) = left(<accno>, 6) then 6
               when left(accno, 5) = left(<accno>, 5) then 5
               when left(accno, 4) = left(<accno>, 4) then 4
               when left(accno, 3) = left(<accno>, 3) then 3
               when left(accno, 2) = left(<accno>, 2) then 2
               when left(accno, 1) = left(<accno>, 1) then 1
               else 0
          end) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: :winces: ...ouch.  However, it'll (probably) generate wrong results: `87325XXXX` should likely not be considered for an account of `824119000`.

Comment: I have tried similar. but it gives more than one row.... fetch first 1 row can give single row but it checks row by row..suppose if the table has 100 rows then this query will check like 12 times for each row.

Comment: I want something like in when class if it is matched then query should stop..suppose if it finds full accno then it should stop there only else then it should match 11 char else 10 char  like that..

Comment: My query is
    
      SELECT ACCNO,TEXT  FROM @tbl
      WHERE
      ( CASE
        when ACCNO = '8611004050001'   then '8611004050001' 
               else
                  case
                      when ACCNO = '861100405000X' then '861100405000X'  
                ELSE '8611XXXXXXXXX'  
                end        
          end) = accno  WITH UR;--

Comment: @DhanyaKUMAR.S - Oh, this query will retrieve the first match it finds (although I've heard rumors the optimizer may mess with that on occasion).  It probably won't always retrieve the correct match.  It has the potential to be ridiculously slow; depending on whether the optimizer is smart enough to partially read index entries for `accno`.

Comment: @DhanyaKUMAR.S . . . This query *cannot* return more than one row.  The `fetch first 1 row only` guarantees that only one row is returned.